# CSRF token mismatch Laravel 10 & NuxtJS

Tags: laravel, axios, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth

My main problem for my setup is that I can't make requests with axios. Always getting 419 for CSRF token mismatch, don't know what to do, looked every article on google, example request with axios:

```
methods: {
    async register() {
        await this.$axios.get('http://localhost:80/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
        await this.$axios.post('http://localhost:80/api/register', {
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password,
        });
    }
}
```

Strange thing is that I can login, receive user and logout just fine. Like so:

```
methods: {
    async logout() {
        await this.$auth.logout()

        await this.$router.push('/login')
    },
},
```

```
methods: {
    async login() {
        await this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
            data: {
                email: 'lapa@lapa.com',
                password: 'slaptas'
            }
        });

        await this.$router.push('/');
    }
}
```

I did try to change domains, checked my setup couple times, everything looks normal.

My laravel backend is running on docker at http://localhost/
My nuxt app is running on http://localhost:3000/

laravel config:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

NuxtJS config:

```
export default {
    head: {
        title: 'appname',
        htmlAttrs: {
            lang: 'en'
        },
        meta: [{
                charset: 'utf-8'
            },
            {
                name: 'viewport',
                content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'
            },
            {
                hid: 'description',
                name: 'description',
                content: ''
            },
            {
                name: 'format-detection',
                content: 'telephone=no'
            }
        ],
        link: [{
            rel: 'icon',
            type: 'image/x-icon',
            href: '/favicon.ico'
        }]
    },

    css: [],

    plugins: [],

    components: true,

    buildModules: [
        '@nuxt/typescript-build',
        '@nuxt/postcss8'
    ],

    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
    ],

    axios: {
        credentials: true
    },

    auth: {
        strategies: {
            'laravelSanctum': {
                provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
                url: 'http://localhost',
                endpoints: {
                    login: {
                        url: '/api/login'
                    },
                    logout: {
                        url: '/api/logout'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    build: {
        transpile: [
            'defu'
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: these routes are in api.php

Comment: @TimLewis as I mention before my login, logout routes works, so why POST with axios doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

So when you are using laravel with sanctum you need to first get the CSRF token, which I see you are doing. Axios should attach it on your behalf, but you may also need to set it. Since you are able to login and then it fails, I wonder if its getting lost in-between requests. You should check if it is in the subsequent request.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#csrf-protection

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you add the "Accept: application/json" header with your request. This resolved the 419 issue I was having.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34632207)